# JavaFX TextArea include empty line with String.split()?

Tags: java, javafx, split, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now but can't quite get it to work.  Essentially I have a JavaFX TextArea and I want to construct a new Object named CommandWrapper with the last line of input (ie. line above caret after the ENTER key is pressed).  Whenever I hit ENTER after typing a command it works flawlessly but for some reason my String.split() function wont get the empty line if I enter no command ash shown in the GIF below:

[image: https://gyazo.com/49ebd82be02fc271eeb7a879b194c63c]

Here is the code concerning the issue:

```
package com.mswordhf.jnet.java.contollers;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import com.mswordhf.jnet.java.models.JnetModel;
import com.mswordhf.jnet.java.modules.CommandWrapper;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;

public class CmdController implements Initializable {

private JnetModel model;
private int clientIndex;

@FXML private TextArea commandTextArea;

public CmdController(JnetModel model, int clientIndex) {
    this.model = model;
    this.clientIndex = clientIndex;
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    commandTextArea.setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> {

        if(keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {

            List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(commandTextArea.getText().split("\\n"));
            String command = lines.get(lines.size() - 1);

            System.out.println(command);

            if(command == "\n") {
                System.out.println("Worked");
            }else {
                CommandWrapper wrapper = new CommandWrapper(command);
                model.getClients().get(clientIndex).getHandle().sendModule(wrapper);

                if(!model.getCmdOutput.isRunning()) {
                    model.getCmdOutput.reset();
                    model.getCmdOutput.start();
                }
            }

        }

    });

    model.getCmdOutput.setOnSucceeded(event -> {

        for(String line : model.getCmdOutput.getValue()) {
            commandTextArea.appendText(line + "\n");
        }

        model.clearList();

    });

}

}
```

Comment: `==` checks for primitive (`int`, `char`, `double`, ...) equality, use `.equals(...)` to check for object (`String`, `Object`, ...) equality. Also [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) does not include the regex that the String was split with in the resulting array. Meaning that `if(command.equals("\\n"))` will always be false, perhaps you should check for the empty String, `if(command.equals(""))`.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Thanks for the comment and you're right I should've been using equals() but the problem remains.  I believe the last empty line isn't being picked up by 'String#split()' because the 'println(command)' always prints the line 2 up from the  caret after pressing ENTER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really uncertain as to why, but using:

```
commandTextArea.setOnKeyReleased(keyevent -> {
    //code...
}
```

works totally as intended.

Comment: I'm puzzled why releasing a key, instead of pressing it, would produce the desired behaviour, but if it works *it works*.

Comment: Oh perhaps the key pressed event is fired before the `\n` is appended to the `commandTextArea`'s text. That's the only reason I can think of. Nice job figuring this out, +1.

Comment: Yeah that's what I've figured must be the case, thanks for helping me out!